# Absolute divs next to eachother

Tags: html, css

In my html page i have two divs inside a container div. The two inner divs have a 'position: aboslute'. Becuase they have to be placed at the bottom left corner of the container div.

This works great when the container div only has one inner div. But when i add a 2nd div, then the 2nd div is placed ontop of the first inner div. Which makes sense ofcourse. But now i'm trying to find a way to have them next to eachother instead of them overlapping eachother.

The inner divs are generated. So i can't manually add an ID to them. All they have is one class name.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sYGfq/):

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="icon">ICON1</div>
    <div class="icon">ICON2</div>
</div>
```

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.icon {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: you could make them relatively positioned, cause then they maintain layout relative to their parent(container) element

Comment: What about placing each ICON in an 'li', as opposed to 'div' element? Styling list items is then very flexible, and simple!

Comment: just use first-child/last-child, see my answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the absolute positioning on a wrapper element instead of each individual icon, then you can float or position the icons how you like within that container:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="icon-wrapper">
      <div class="icon">ICON1</div>
      <div class="icon">ICON2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.icon {
    border: 1px solid green;
    float:left;
}
.icon-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sYGfq/3/

Answer (score 0):

If there are only 2 you can use :first-child or :last-child in the css, no need to add extra html. A few lines of css will take care of it

example here http://jsfiddle.net/sYGfq/6/

CSS for last child

```
.icon:last-child {
    left: 200px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don't think last-child is supported in IE7 (not sure about IE8).

Comment: then use first-child, one of them is supported, see http://jsfiddle.net/sYGfq/8/ in IE 7

Comment: @Huangism Did you check that in IE, because one of them falls out of the container div. Besides, what good does 'first-child' do when you have 3 or more icons.

Comment: @Vivendi I did the first child in IE 7 but on VM. It falls out because I set left to 200. In his question he only mentions 2 and so does my answer. If there are more icons it is not apparent i the question

Answer (score 0):

Put both of the divs into seperate cells in a table, remove all borders and padding from the table and absolutely position it at the bottom-left hand corner of the parent div.

```
<div id="container">
<table class="none" id="table1">
<tr class="none">
<td class="none">
<div class="icon">ICON1</div>
</td>
<td class="none">
<div class="icon">ICON2</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

---

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.icon {
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.none {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#table1 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Presto!